# paraboloid parameterisation

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

In my question I am given:

[image]

The paraboloid has height 2 and maximum radius 2.

I am asked to enter the parameterisation

p(r,t)=(x(r,t),y(r,t),z(r,t)), such that 0≤r<2 and 0≤t<2π gives the paraboloid surface above.

I have been playing around on some graphing packages to find the parameterisation p(r,t), and so far I have
p(r,t) = [rcos(t), rsin(t), r^2].

The above parameterisation meets the radius requirements, however, for my above parameterisation, when graphed, the height is 4, when it should be 2. I have been playing around with the x, y and x components, but I am not sure how to reduce this height.

I appreciate any help,
thank u!

Comment: Scale the $z$-coordinate so that you do get the right height when $r=2$.

Comment: Since $r^2=z$, $r$ must be $\sqrt{2}$ for a height of 2. So, your range of parametrization must be $0\leq r < \sqrt{2}$ and $0\leq t < 2\pi$.

Comment: @Zxcvasdf $0\le r\lt2$ is a given condition of the problem.